# document.referrer is blank in firefox and chrome on SSL redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, referrer, http-status-code-302

document.referrer in javascript is blank from a 302 redirect from http to https using a F5 load balancer in Firefox and Chrome, but shows up in IE.  Is there a reason for this or a way around to detect the referrer?

Comment: Don't rely on REFERER. It was a terrible idea that should never have been perpetuated. If you need to keep track of history, do it explicitly with a URL query parameter.

Comment: Are you going from a page served over `https://` to an `http://` link which redirects to `https://` automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a security feature when redirecting/linking cross-protocol sites.

There is never a way to detect the correct referrer, because clients can easily spoof or disable them.